# Increase in RSS in a parallel program due to MPI datatype

Tags: list, rss, fortran, mpi

I am testing a Fortran MPI parallel program, that I have been developing, and it will be great if I can get some info on the issue I seem to be having with MPI Datatype.

My program needs to send a linked list to its neighboring cores, which it does by packing the data and creating an MPI STRUCT. The number of nodes in the linked list is not constant and keeps changing in between the MPI_Send/Recv calls, so I have to free and commit the MPI datatype as and when required.

When I look at the output of the top command, and also from reading the contents of/proc/self/statm I find that the RSS size constantly increases (my code is running now and it has increased from 9 MB to 12 GB). I tried to find out if there was a certain point in the program where this increase is large, but it seems to be a steady increase. I was able to narrow down the location of this increase to the routine where the MPI Struct is being created.

I made some changes to my program so that the arrays used for creating the MPI datatype (data count and displacement arrays), and the arrays to receive the data are not allocated/deallocated during each MPI Send/Recv call, but only when the number of nodes being received is larger than that in the previous call. I create the MPI_Struct by using the count and displacement data from the relevant indexes before sending/receiving. But these changes don't seem to be helping me because I am still having to make a call to MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT and MPI_TYPE_COMMIT for each MPI Send/Recv pair.

My queries are the following:

a) Is it efficient to use linked lists to gather the data that needs to be sent, if we don't know how much data has to be sent to allocate an array for it? If so has anyone encountered a problem of an increasing RSS due to creating the MPI Struct for each MPI Send? I am considering if it is more efficient to copy the linked list data to an array that can be sent, instead of creating an MPI datatype for the linked list. Any thoughts on this will be appreciated.

b) Even when I call MPI_TYPE_FREE after the MPI_Send/Recv I don't see any decrease in the RSS. I am assuming that even though the memory is being freed, it's not being returned to the OS. Should I be meddling with any environment variables (M_TRIM_THRESHOLD) to make sure that released memory is sent back to the OS immediately? But I am not sure if this works for Fortran

I am using the Intel compiler 14.0 with Intel MPI.

Thanks

nty

Comment: Did you try any memory leak debugging tool?

Comment: It would help if you could substantiate your question with some concrete code samples.

Comment: Yes I tried using valgrind but couldn't pinpoint any location where the leak is. I will look through the outputs again and see if I find something.  

About code examples, not sure how to provide this. I will give it a try.

Comment: Vladimir is possibly referring to MPICH's "--enable-g=mem" option, which will tell you a bit about what kind of MPI resource is being leaked (memory, comm, datatype, info, etc)